# How do I turn html tags in word to formatted text

Tags: microsoft-word, html, mail-merge

I'm trying to make multiple documents using mail merge and an access database, but there is one field where in Access I have it saved as rich text. I need it as rich text because it's a single field with different formatting throughout, but when I do the mail merge, it comes out as html tags.

I need a macro or something that can turn the html tags into formatted text.

```
<div><font face="Knowledge Medium" color="#595959">Introduction (30 min.)</font></div>

<div><font color="#595959">Environment</font></div>

<div><font color="#595959">Platform</font></div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div><font face="Knowledge Medium" color="#595959">Getting Started (30 min.)</font></div>

<div><font color="#595959">Overview</font></div>

<div><font color="#595959">Terms</font></div>

<div><font color="#595959">Areas</font></div>
```

Comment: Either change the angle brackets to "escaped" brackets &lt; and &gt;, or output to a different format (like raw text?) that doesn't attempt to interpret html.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it in a Word (.docx) file, but would saving it as a Web Page within Word if you want the formatted text work?